# Regex for query in posgtresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a tag name that follows this templante

`abc_abcd_L{x}_AB1L{x}_abcabc_abcbabc`

what i need is a regex to use in a query where {x} is a number from 1 to 4, i mean, i want to match everything exactly as above the only character that changes is the number inside {}, so my tad description is:

`abc_abcd_L1_AB1L1_abcabc_abcbabc`
`abc_abcd_L2_AB1L2_abcabc_abcbabc`
`abc_abcd_L3_AB1L3_abcabc_abcbabc`

so only the number after both 'L' changes.   How can i code this regex for a query in Postgresql?

Thnaks

Answer (score -1):

Though I don't know postgresql, here's the standard regex solution for it:

```
abc_abcd_L([1-4])_AB1L\1_abcabc_abcbabc
```

**[Which you can try out here](https://regex101.com/r/ZcyMn0/1)**

## Explanation:

I'm using a feature of regex that's supported in all languages as far as I know, called named groups. Basically, everything inside parentheses in regex is a group, and each group has an id based on it's position in the regex. In this case, the group `([1-4])` is at a position of 1, so we refer to it with the callback operator, `\1`.

**EDIT:** I overlooked the fact that the digit had to be between 1 and 4, so I changed `\d` to `[1-4]`